# PHP santization of textarea input

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, escaping

My application will accept textarea content that is submitted by a user, and i would like some people to review my code to make sure there is no security vulnerability such as XSS.

My mySQL column that will save this information is a column of type `TEXT` and is not required and nullable.

When storing the data to database, my script is doing the following:

```
// to avoid inserting html tags in the database
$input = str_replace(["<", ">"],"", $_POST['userinput'])

// to avoid saving problematic characters such as quotes 
$cleanInput = htmlentities(input , ENT_QUOTES)

// store the content
$addPostStmt = $conn -> prepare("
  INSERT INTO posts(description) VALUES ( ?)
");

$addPostStmt -> bind_param("s", $cleanInput); 
$addPostStmtExecute = $addPostStmt -> execute();
```

When presenting the data to the user, the script is doing the following:

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars(html_entity_decode($post['description']), ENT_SUBSTITUTE); ?>
```

Comment: What's the logic behind doing htmlspecialchars/ html_entity_decode/ then htmlspecialchars again?

Comment: @YourCommonSense not sure what you mean by htmlspecialchars again, i am only doing it one, after decoding the html entities. its mostly incase something slips through

Comment: htmlspecialchars and htmlentities is virtually the same, so what's the point doing the same job twice?

Comment: Or to put it the other way, what's the point in doing entity encode and then decode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, don't do that. You seem to be filtering and escaping values out of paranoia rather than understanding what exactly would lead to a vulnerability. As a result, you are corrupting your data.

A well designed application should use the database to store the value that the user typed into the textarea, not some mangled representation of it. If you mangle the data like that before storing it, then:

- Certain characters that the user typed get dropped. (What if the user input is `x + 3 < 5`? The data would no longer make sense after you drop the `<` character.)
- Your database is not reliably searchable. (What if the user input is `She said "yes!"`? Then you would store a value in the database with `&quot;` in it.)
- If you arbitrarily apply escaping to string just in case, then you'll have a hard time keeping track of how to unescape it correctly when regurgitating the data. (This often leads to bugs where the user sees garbage like `his &amp; hers`, or even worse, `his &amp;amp; hers`.)

What's the right way? Don't mangle the data; just store it faithfully:

```
// store the content
$addPostStmt = $conn -> prepare("
  INSERT INTO posts(description) VALUES (?)
");

$addPostStmt -> bind_param("s", $_POST['userinput']); 
$addPostStmtExecute = $addPostStmt -> execute();
```

When outputting the data as HTML, apply HTML escaping:

```
<th>Description:</th><td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($description); ?></td>
```

Comment: escaping values out of paranoia, that is correct tbh. As i dont have a alot of experience with php and mysql, i chose to be very careful to what to add to my database.



1. `<` and `>` does not get used usually when writing content like articles and description. So i thought it would be safer to remove it. The content wont be related to math but i see your point. But instead of filtering out these character, is ok to filter `<script` instead in case someday i forgot to use `htmlspecialchars`

Comment: 2. and 3. True and i completely agree, but the reason i chose to do it like that is because i was not really certain if there where any magical/non-visible character that might cause a problem with sql. But as long i am using prepared statments i guess i should be fine. Are there edge case scenarios that i should be aware of,  where having quote characters in the database might be dangerous?

Comment: Nothing more to worry about. You're using the database API correctly. Just trust that it does the right thing, and don't apply any extra data-corrupting transformations. As long you call `htmlspecialchars()` when outputting the string as HTML, that will correctly take care of XSS concerns.

Comment: just a side question, why did you drop the `ENT_SUBSTITUTE` flag ?

Comment: Because `html_entity_decode()` should be unnecessary altogether, if you don't apply a superfluous round of encoding with `htmlentities()`.